# IT Special Visa clarification

Tags: germany, german-citizens, pr

I am from India and have been living in the UK for last 4 years. I am planning to move to Germany with an IT Specialist visa. Can I apply for permanent residency (PR) after 1 year since I was in the EU for 4 years?

Comment: Close, if not exactly a duplicate: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/does-moving-to-a-second-eu-country-with-a-permanent-residence-from-the-another-c

Comment: Question is unclear, we need details on what kind of residence permit do you have in UK?

Comment: I've closed this, but you can still edit it. Just specifiy what current visa you have for the UK, and what visa you are going to obtain in Germany. I think the linked question answer this though.