# Moving from one EU country to Another for residence

Tags: germany, resident-permit, netherlands, europe

Currently, I am living in Germany for over 3 years. Previously, I have lived in Netherlands for 7 years. Is it possible that these 7 years in Netherlands can be accounted to get permanent residence in Germany.

I have read on the forum that pension is transferable.

Note: I don't have permanent residence of Netherlands.

**The previous questions assume that you have permanent residence in one EU country**

Comment: No because, I don't have permanent residence of Netherlands

Comment: but the answer to the question I mentioned would also answer your question. If even some types of permanent residence permit do not help to get permanent residency in Germany, then without it you cannot get anything accounted.

Comment: one more question - if you live in Germany for over 3 years, were you eligible for the Blue Card?

Comment: Since my flag with the related question has diappeared, here it is again: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/9586/13223

Comment: I have mentioned the reason, why this question is different from previous one

Comment: @cswah The difference is clear but you have now received a comprehensive answer. There isn't really much more to day, if you didn't secure a permanent resident permit back when you were in the Netherlands, the time spent there doesn't have any relevance for your status in Germany. Pensions can indeed be consolidated but that's an entirely different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the time spent in the Netherlands does not count towards either permanent/long-term resident statuses available in Germany.

Comment: But this may change: https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2023/11/23/third-country-nationals-eu-updates-rules-for-long-term-resident-status/