# Leaving Italy and moving to Germany

Tags: germany, italy, relocation

I will move to Germany after staying in Italy for over four years. In those four years, three years were register at inps through Gestione Separata and one year as a researcher.

Can someone let me know, how I can transfer my pension from Italy to Germany.

In addition, please let me know which steps should I perform to gracefully exit Italy.

Comment: In this question you state that you live in Italy. In another one, the Netherlands: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/21105/13223. If you are asking questions for other people, it would be nice if you could encourage them to register their own account and ask themselves, or if you would state that in your question. This helps provide context for those who want to try to give a useful complete answer to your question.

Comment: @AndreySapegin, On this site, I don't mind if people ask questions for other people or just to 'get reputation' as long as the questions meet our quality guidelines and are of use to the site and to those who might come here looking for such information.